# How to implement InstallStateUpdatedListener for In-App Update API?

Tags: android

As per the documentation for flexible update , we will allow user to use app. And show snackbar with action when downloading is complete. Showing app update dialog is done in Activity A and then we are moving to another activity. Now when downloading is complete I will be active on any activity say Activity N or any random Activity within app. Now how I should register InstallStateUpdatedListener and handle this for any activity?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add:

`implements InstallStateUpdatedListener` next to your class.

Example: `public class MyAwesomeClass implements InstallStateUpdatedListener`

After that, you just implement `InstallStateUpdatedListener` in case of flexible In-App Update, you have to use its `onStateUpdate` to get the overall progress of your update:

```
@Override
public void onStateUpdate(InstallState installState) {
    switch (installState.installStatus()) {
        case InstallStatus.DOWNLOADING:
            log("Downloading update...");
            break;
        case InstallStatus.DOWNLOADED:
            notifyUser();
            break;
        case InstallStatus.FAILED:          
            break;
        case InstallStatus.CANCELED:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Update download cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case InstallStatus.INSTALLED:                
            break;
    }
}
```

and to register that listener, you just have to do something like:

```
AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager = 
AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this.getReactApplicationContext());
    appUpdateManager.registerListener(this);
```